# How to check for user permissions without security breaches in javascript?

Tags: javascript, security

I am new to Javascript and have been using a global boolean hasAccessPermissions that retrieves data from an API to store if the user has admin privileges or not.
And with this data, I am showing some elements of the screen only to admin users. However, I've been told that it is a security breach, since the non-admin user has access to this code and can see and alter what he sees by editing my boolean locally.

How can I hide UI elements based on user access privileges in JS 'the correct way' ?

Comment: JS runs in the browser, and therefore is not secure. You'll need to handle user access on the server

Comment: I've thought about creating two similar webpages, one with admin features and the other exactly the same but without them. And then handling which page will be presented to the user on the server side. But this sounds more like a workaround than an actual solution to me... that's why I've decided to reach out looking for alternatives from the community

Comment: Everything that gets run in the browser can be viewed and modified by the user. For example, your `hasAccessPermissions` boolean can simply be changed in the browser console. Obviously I have no idea what your architecture is so it's hard to make suggestions. If you're using an API, can it handle user authentication/requests? That way even if a user modifies the DOM to reveal some admin button, the API request thats triggered won't perform unless they are authenticated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question, since it's been a while without an answer.

You don't. Everything that runs in JS can be viewed and modified by the user, you would need to handle user permissions on the server-side.